# Jquery: Uncaught TypeError Illegal Invocation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I was following webpage to learn about displaying data from mysql without page refresh:-
http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/load%20data%20from%20database%20without%20page%20refresh%20using%20ajax%20and%20jquery.php

Following are the 2 files
File1: displaydata.html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function load_data() {

      var name = document.getElementById("guestname");

      if (name) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'loaddata.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
            guest_name: name,
          },
          success: function(response) {

            // We get the element having id of display_info and put the response inside it
            $('#display_info').html(response);
            //document.getElementById('display_info').innerHTML = response;
          }
        });

      } else {
        $('#display_info').html("Please Enter Some Words");
      }

    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" name="guestname" id="guestname" onKeyUp="load_data();">

  <div id="display_info">

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

File2: loaddata.php

```html
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$pw='';
$db='yoigo';
$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
 printf("Connect failed: %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());
 exit();
} else {
 echo "Jatinder!";
}

if( isset( $_POST['guest_name'] ) )
//if(1)
{

$name = $_POST['guest_name'];

$sql = " SELECT lastname,email FROM myguests WHERE firstname LIKE '$name%' ";

$result = $connect->query($sql);

if($result === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
  $rows_returned = $result->num_rows;
}
echo $rows_returned . ' rows returned.' . '<br> <br>';

 if ($rows_returned > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
   echo "<p>".$row[0]."</p>";
   echo "<p>".$row[1]."</p>";
  } 
 }
}
?>
```

I am frustrated by this illegal invocation error of jquery. Not sure why its coming. Could anyone please guide?

Thanks,
Jatinder

Comment: try adding this to your ajax `processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
                contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType`

Comment: You are sending the object `var name = document.getElementById("guestname");`/`data: { guest_name: name, },`, and not just its value. Change `var name = document.getElementById("guestname");` to `var name = document.getElementById("guestname").value;` OR using jquery `var name = $("$guestname").val();`

Comment: Thanks Guradio and Sean! :) You guys are awesome!  It worked!